# How are variable length arguments parsed while parsing dalvik instructions?

Tags: dalvik, opcode, instructions

Both `move vA, vB` and `move-wide vA, vB` involve the same operations and same operands. Except opcodes everything is the same. I am in a situation where I need to print the operands used by instructions in an application.
So when I see the instruction `move vA, vB` I should print `move va(*contents of va*), vb(*contents of vb*)`. 

This works fine in the case of 4-byte registers. But when I encounter `move-wide` instructions, I should print the contents of vA and the contents of the next virtual register., contents of vB and the contents of the next virtual register. 
 What is the standard way of parsing these?

Comment: "What is the standard way of parsing these?" Are you asking how to combine the values of the 2 registers in the pair to come up with the single 64-bit value to display?

Comment: Can you come on chat? I could explain it better there?

Comment: I have created a room called dalvik

Comment: However, without using the opcode itself, is there a way to find out if 2 registers are being used or one?

Comment: By 2 registers, I mean for one operand.

Comment: No. You need to know the opcode to know how to interpret the rest of the instruction. That said, there are only a limited number of instruction layouts, including argument interpretation. Each of these interpretations is an instruction format. You can map opcodes to instruction formats and then only implement the couple or dozen instruction format interpreters. You can see this implemented in dexdump (well, libdex), baksmali, and dx.

Answer (score 0):

Since both Dalvik and dx are open source, the best way to answer questions involving dex files is to inspect their source. Dx parses instructions in [DecodedInstruction.java](https://github.com/android/platform_dalvik/blob/master/dx/src/com/android/dx/io/instructions/DecodedInstruction.java). It decodes the opcode first, and then uses the opcode to inform decoding the rest of the instruction.

```
public static DecodedInstruction decode(CodeInput in) throws EOFException {
    int opcodeUnit = in.read();
    int opcode = Opcodes.extractOpcodeFromUnit(opcodeUnit);
    InstructionCodec format = OpcodeInfo.getFormat(opcode);
    return format.decode(opcodeUnit, in);
}
```